# HTMl Import own WebComponent

Tags: javascript, html, import, platform, web-component

In my index.html I import an external HTML file with an Template, Shadow DOM etc. A custom web Component.

//  index.html

```
... 
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/polymer/0.3.4/platform.js"></script>
<link rel="import" href="/html-components/userlogin-header.html" >
<head>
<body>
<userlogin-header username="Test User"userimage="http://domain.com/img.jpg"></userlogin-header>
...
```

And the other file userlogin-header.html:

// userlogin-header.html

```
<template id="userlogin-header">

    <div class="imgbox">
        <img src="" class="userimage">
    </div>
    <div class="userinfo">                          
        <div class="name"><span class="username"></div>                     
    </div>
</template>


<script>
    var doc = this.document.currentScript.ownerDocument,
    UserLoginProto = Object.create( HTMLElement.prototype );
    UserLoginProto.createdCallback = function() {
        var template = doc.querySelector( "#userlogin-header" ),
        box = template.content.cloneNode( true );

        this.shadow = this.createShadowRoot();
        this.shadow.appendChild( box );

        var username = this.shadow.querySelector( '.userinfo .username' );
        username.innerHTML = ( this.getAttribute( 'username' ) || 'Unbekannt' );

        var imageurl = this.shadow.querySelector( 'img.userimage' );

        imageurl.src = 'https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/' + this.getAttribute( 'userimage' ) + '1?s=40&d=http://s3-01.webmart.de/web/support_user.png';
    };

     var Xuserlogin = doc.registerElement( 'userlogin-header', { 'prototype' : UserLoginProto } );
</script>
```

The problem is that there is the following error on call index.html

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'content' of null
```

If I enable HTML Import in my Chrome everything works correctly. But then I disable this and use platform.js instead there is this error.

Is there any solution for this problem? I do not want to use the whole polymer framework.

Comment: Is platform.js the very first included file in your `<head>`?

Comment: Yes, this is the first include directly after the <title>

Answer (score 5):

This is a symptom of [this caveat](http://www.polymer-project.org/platform/html-imports.html#other-notes) of the polyfill.

> In a native HTML Imports, `document.currentScript.ownerDocument`
>   references the import document itself. In the polyfill use
>   `document._currentScript.ownerDocument` (note the underscore).

Once you change that, you also need to use *document*.registerElement instead of *doc*.registerElement. You want to register the element such that it's visible to the *importing* document, not the imported one.

```
var Xuserlogin = document.registerElement(...);
```

Here's a [working plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/jsb5bP8kwDDt10VqxeNB?p=preview).